# How to check SQL Agent Service account has access to the UNC directory

Tags: sql-server, unc

I'm currently using this query to figure out if the SQL has permissions,

EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist '\servername\sharename'

But this query is running as the user I'm logged in as, Is there any way I can execute it as SQL Agent Service Account to check if that user has access?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, `sql_agent` runs under `system\NetworkService` account and it don't have access to UNC path (OR) other computers.

You can change the account which runs `sql_agent` by going to `control panel -> services` OR `Sql server configuration manager`.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't want to change the SQL Agent account. I want to run my query shown above manually but execute it as SQL Agent account

Comment: As said, SQL Agent runs under Network_service account which don't have access to UNC shares.

Answer (score 0):

The following script should get you what you are after:

```
USE master
GO

DECLARE @ServiceAcct sysname, @Path as varchar(256)
SET @Path = '\\UNC\Path\To\Test\Access'

EXECUTE  dbo.xp_instance_regread
    @rootkey      = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    @key          = N'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLServer',
    @value_name   = N'ObjectName',
    @value        = @ServiceAcct OUTPUT

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = @ServiceAcct;
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @Path

EXECUTE       master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
              @rootkey      = N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
              @key          = N'SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\SQLServerAgent',
              @value_name   = N'ObjectName',
              @value        = @ServiceAcct OUTPUT

EXECUTE AS LOGIN = @ServiceAcct;
EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist @Path
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd Rahul that the agent cannot read UNC paths. I change the SQL Agent Service to run under a Service Account that is part of the domain. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/set-service-startup-account-sql-server-agent-sql-server-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: @Gourav I'd argue that "change the SQL Agent Service to run under a Service Account that is part of the domain" qualifies as an answer, with our without the link.