# Compare two text files but one doesn't exist due to permissions

Tags: c#-4.0, ssis

I am attempting to compare two text files in a Script Task in an SSIS Package.  Both files exist in the file system.  Both files are in the same directory.  However, one does not exist because the permissions setup do not see the file.

The code below is not working.  I have tried a few different variations of the code below and the SSIS Package continues to go forward, ultimately failing on a subsequent File System Task because doesn't have access to the file.

I am attempting to capture that the file is not present because the package does not have access to the file, and not because the file isn't there.  Originally, I was using `File.Exists()`, however, that won't work because it returns `false` whether the file is not there or the package does not have access to it.

```
    string packageName = Dts.Variables["System::PackageName"].Value.ToString();
    string taskName = Dts.Variables["System.TaskName"].Value.ToString();

    string inputFilePath = Dts.Variables["User::inputFilePath"].Value.ToString();
    string processedFilePath = Dts.Variables["User::processedFilePath"].Value.ToString();

    bool blnFilesMatch = true;

    try
    {
        int i = 0, j = 0;

        // Compare the source and processed files to determine if the contents are different.
        using (var f1 = new FileStream(inputFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        using (var f2 = new FileStream(processedFilePath, FileMode.Open))
        {
            do
            {
                i = f1.ReadByte();
                j = f2.ReadByte();

                if (i != j)
                    break;

            } while (i != -1 && j != -1);

            if (i != j)
                blnFilesMatch = false;  // Files Differ
            else
                blnFilesMatch = true;   // Files are the same
        }

        Dts.Variables["User::blnIdenticalFiles"].Value = blnFilesMatch;

        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        string tempFileName = "temp_" + packageName + ".txt.";
        string tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(inputFilePath), tempFileName);

        // A file wasn't found.  Try to create and delete a temp file to determine whether it was because of permissions or if the file just was not present.
        try
        {
            File.Create(tempFilePath);
            File.Delete(tempFilePath);
            Dts.Variables["User::blnIdenticalFiles"].Value = false;
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException uae)
        {
            // Permissions cannot create the file.
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, packageName + " - " + taskName, uae.Message, string.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Dts.Events.FireError(0, packageName + " - " + taskName, ex.Message, string.Empty, 0);
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
    }
```

Comment: I'm not really following here. You say `Originally, I was using File.Exists(), however, that won't work because it returns false whether the file is not there or the package does not have access to it.` If your package user agent doesn't have permissions to the file, then it should be considered that it doesn't exist, right? Or are you trying to do something else here? What is your actual downstream problem or error?

Comment: I'm trying or wanting to capture a permissions error being the result of the file not being there.  If I look for the file, the file exists.  However, if the package user agent looks for the file, the file is not there.  `File.Exists` returns true for me, but false for the agent.  Downstream, the agent also can't create or update the file name of the `inputFile`; however. _is there a scenario where it would be able to do this, but still not see the_ `processedFile`

Comment: Here's the thing though, if the agent is the one that runs the package, you'll be limited to seeing only what the agent has permissions to see. The agent won't be able to know if there are files it can't see, because it can't see them. As for your last question, yes, it's possible for an account to have write permissions but not read permissions. The user would be able to write a file, but wouldn't be able to see the file.

Comment: Is there an easy/way to test the permissions of the agent in order to ensure that the permissions exist or fail the package at that point if permissions do not exist?

Comment: I came across this question, which may have some info you need: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196350/how-to-check-sql-agent-service-account-has-access-to-the-unc-directory
`EXEC master.dbo.xp_fileexist <path>` looks especially useful